# New In Java and want to learn how to use Java Parse

Tags: java

Please help me in writing a Program that takes a single digit or value from user and then prints whether the value is an Alphabet or a number or a special character. And if the input is alphabet  then determines whether its vowel or not. I don't Know how to use the Builtin Java functions coz am new to java. Below is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class myClass {

  public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter The Value To Check: ");

    int N=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){

    if(N==i) {

        System.out.println("You Entered A Number");
        break;
     }

    }

    if(N=='a'||N=='A' ||N=='z'   ||N=='Z') {

      System.out.println("You Entered An Alphabet");

    }


    for(int k=128; k<=255; k++){

        if (N==k){

        System.out.println("You Enter A Special Character");

        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add a homework tag if this is homework

Comment: Do your your homework. :) Hint: Look into regex. It probably solves your issue.

Comment: @Nishant - Suggesting regex for someone that is obviously a complete beginner is not a good thing.  It will only confuse them more.

Comment: especially since regex is an overkill here even for experts.

Comment: @KennethFunk agree. But if you have just a character to test for whether it's digit, or word, or non-word charatcer. The regex for this is quite simple. However [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9588566/298455) is simpler.

Comment: @Farhan - I would suggest using .Next instead of .NextInt() with Scanner since you input can be anything.

Comment: Yes i don't want regex yet i just want to know how to use the builtin fucntions used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing ASCII with ASCII encoded decimals... nextInt() returns next integer, which won't work if you enter say ?, &, * etc. Use the hasNext() method to check what's available first

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.println("You Entered A Number " + input.nextInt());
} else if (input.hasNext("\\w")) {
  System.out.println("You Entered An Alphabet " + input.next());
} else {
  System.out.println("You Enter A Special Character");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is homework - I'll only hint.

Have a look at [`Character.isLetter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) and [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)

Another hint: have a look at the ascii values of 'a','A','z','Z' - what is in common for all letters, regards to these ascii values?

I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Farhan: You are most welcome, and good luck with your assigment. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have found one useuful.